# Printing Japanese text character-by-character doesn't work

Tags: c++, utf-8

I have a std::string containing a sequence of bytes (characters) in an unknown coding format. (There are a few possibilities and I'm working to convert them to UTF-8)

My test program prints the string correctly to my terminal using both std::cout and printf with .c_str(), but printing character by character produces *mojibake*.

Other posts say that std::string contains just a sequence of bytes, so why would it make a difference if the bytes were output all at once (via std::cout or c_str()) versus one at a time?

```
void
dumpString(const std::string &s)
{
    printf("dumpString: '%s'\n", s.c_str());

    std::cout << "cout:   " << s << std::endl;

    printf("By chars: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = s.at(i);
        printf("%c ", c);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("By Hex: ");
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = s.at(i);
        printf("%1X ", (unsigned char)c);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Program output]

Comment: "char" is only an 8-bit Ascii char. you can't  use that as a placeholder for a unicode string char.

Comment: Why are you conveting the chars to unsigned chars?

Comment: Also you are printing a space after each char, this will corrupt the multi-byte `UTF-8` values. `UTF-8` characters can be up to `4` char's long.

Comment: Galik, YES, that was the problem.  Dumb mistake.  Thank you.

Comment: @JasonLang but outputting a multibyte character byte-by-byte is certainly possible.